# Understanding the behavior of $f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)= \sum_i y^2_i - \frac{\left(\sum_i x_i y^2_i \right)^2}{\sum_i x^2_iy^2_i} $

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have the following function $f: \mathbb R^N \times \mathbb R^N \rightarrow \mathbb R$.
$$f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)= \sum_i y^2_i - \frac{\left(\sum_i x_i y^2_i \right)^2}{\sum_i x^2_iy^2_i} $$
where $x_i$ is an $i^{th}$ coordinate value of $\mathbf x$. Note that the first term is just the L2 norm of $\mathbf y$ (i.e. $\| \mathbf y \|_F^2$). So far, I see the following properties:

1. $ 0\leq f(\mathbf x, \mathbf y) \leq \| \mathbf y \|_F^2 $ for all $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ (but not positive definite since the function is asymmetric)
2. $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=0$ when $x_i$ values are uniform!
3. $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=\| \mathbf y \|_F^2$ when $\mathbf x$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf y_2$ a vector whose elements are squares of that of $\mathbf y$.

I am disregarding the trivial cases when the length of either one of the vectors is $0$. What are some other observations that we can make? More specifically, in what other cases would $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)=0$?

Also, is there a way to quantify the uniformness of $x_i$ and how that is related to the deviation from / closeness to $0$?

In my study, $x_i\geq0$ (singular values) and $N\rightarrow \infty$, but for this post, I will relax those constraints. This function emerges from a fairly complicated computation involving tricks from statistical physics (i.e. the replica method, saddle point method etc.).